# Pass context to template in dynamically created component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to create an component like a tooltip control. The problem is that it only works for simple text but when I want to pass a little more complex ng-template (like bindings etc.) it breaks. In general I've created a host component where passed template will be shown and a directive which creates the component.
But it seems like passed context isn't visible for the passed template.

Directive:

```
@HostListener("mouseenter")
enter() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomContainerComponent);
    const injector = Injector.create([]);

    this.vcr.createComponent<CustomContainerComponent>(factory, 0, injector, this.generate());
}

generate(): any[][] {
    const context = { // this is mocked for now
      name:"John"
    };
    const viewRef = this.customControl.createEmbeddedView(context);

    return [viewRef.rootNodes];
}
```

Here is stackblitz with a simple example of the case:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzhccs

Comment: Try this on app.component.html... the values are being updated - but on the first button only `<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
<button [customControl]="ctrl2">Working</button>
<button [customControl]="ctrl1">Not working</button>
</div>

<ng-template #ctrl2>
  Working
</ng-template>
<ng-template #ctrl1 let-name="name">
  not-working: {{name}}
</ng-template>`

Comment: There still does not work binding with the context (name isn't showing). I've managed to make it working, in the directive I changed `this.customControl.createEmbeddedView(context);` to `this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.customControl, context);` and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

viewRef detechange does the trick:

```js
const viewRef = content.templateRef.createEmbeddedView(context);
viewRef.detectChanges();
```

And then the context will be properly populated and bound to the template as expected.

Comment: Wow, this finally solved our problem! Thanks so much